# How to print a message after `autocmd` is done

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, autocmd, ctags

I'm using `ctags` to generate tag file so that I can jump to declaration or to definition while working with C/C++ project.

To make `ctags` work automatically while entering vim, I add such a line in my  `.vimrc`:

```
autocmd VimEnter * silent! !eval 'ctags -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q --language-force=C++ -o newtags; mv newtags .tags;' &
```

As you see, this command won't block because of `&`.

Now, I want to make sure that a message will be printed at the bottom of the window of vim after this command is done. How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it as a background job (`:help job`). Maybe like this:

```
function CtagsExit(cwd, job_id, exit_code)
    if a:exit_code == 0
        call rename(a:cwd . '/newtags', a:cwd . '/.tags')
        echo "Ctags finished with 0"
    else
        echo "Ctags finished with " . a:exit_code . " (execute :messages to see output)"
    endif
endfunction

function CtagsOutput(channel, data)
    echomsg a:data
endfunction

function CtagsStartup()
    let cmdline='ctags -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q --language-force=C++ -o newtags'
    let options = {
                \   'in_io': "null",
                \   'out_cb': "CtagsOutput",
                \   'err_cb': "CtagsOutput",
                \   'exit_cb': function('CtagsExit', [ getcwd() ])
                \ }
    call job_start(cmdline, options)
endfunction

autocmd VimEnter * call CtagsStartup()
```

Update: Handle changing directory while `ctags` is running.
Update 2: Handle output.

Comment: I got an error: `CtagsStartup: line 2: using Funcref as a String`

Comment: @Yves What Vim version do you use? Which OS?

Comment: Vim version: 7.4 OS:Ubuntu16.04.3

Comment: Oops, now it works. I made a copy mistake.

Comment: @Yves I realized, that the first version will fail, as soon as ctags produces any output. I updated the script.

Comment: Great, well done :D

Comment: Instead of `echo`, you can use `popup_notification` for better experience